# Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'requied' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest, uses-feature

I am trying to get my android app to be able to open my camera so I would be able to take a photo. I am currently following a tutorial left by Thenewboston on youtube. I feel that I have follow his code exactly but I seem to getting a problem he did. I am trying implement the

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

which was both found in the video and the link below. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html
https://youtu.be/my8PSy2DBsY?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl&t=239

The two errors I am getting are 
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'requied' in package 
'android'
I dont understand why required was changed in requied
and

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was a glitch with android studios not running my most upto date version of my Manifest.xml I restarted the program and it worked.

I thank you again Alex.